# Overlapping of android Keyboard - Real Solution

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have made hundreds of layout but when this type of situation comes, the android keyboard always overlaps with the edit text or the button below. Everytime I use some tricks and tips to solve it, but yet I have never found  a real dedicated solution.

Here I want that when android keyboard comes, I want that my button should also come above the keyboard, but here it is overlapping.

Please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFBB3A"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_registered_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Registered and Guest Account"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/unselected" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="Button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` this in your activity.

Comment: @MuraliGanesan already done. no difference at all

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest file under your activity include

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".

So that there will be an auto adjust of your content without overlapping.